# javascriptで論理積がtrueを返してくれない

Tags: javascript, jquery

初歩的な質問ですが、ご教授ください。
次の年月日を取得し、xxxx-yy-zz という日付のフォーマットを返す関数checkAttr()を考えます。

```
'use strict'
// setDate
setDate() 
function setDate(){
  var today = new Date();
  var str = checkAttr(String(today.getFullYear()), String(today.getMonth()+1), String(today.getDate()));
  console.log(str)
}

function checkAttr(a,b,c){
  if(b.lenght === 1 && c.length === 1){
    console.log("Hoi")
    b = "0" + b;
    c = "0" + c;
  } else if(b.length === 1) {
    console.log("Hoihoi")
    b = "0" + b;
  } else if(c.length === 1) {
    c = "0" + c;
  }

  return a + "-" + b + "-" + c;
}
```

checkAttr()が呼ばれた時点での仮引数は、例えば本日だと`a="2017", b="1", c="2"`になります。
最初のifに入る前に、それぞれの型は、bはStringでb.lengthはNumberになります。(cも同様)
よって最初のif文の条件の左辺`b.length===1`はtrueになりますし、当然`c.length===1`もtrueです。

論理積は`true && true`になり、trueを返すのでコンソール上にHoiと表示されるのを期待していたのですが、chromeやNodeで確認したところ、実際は最初の条件式はfalseになり、二番目の分岐に処理が移動し、Hoihoiと表示されました。
なぜ最初の論理積はfalseになったのでしょうか？

Comment: `b.lenght` は、 `b.length` のタイプミス

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: タイポ質問です。

Comment: おお、そんなことでしたか。
つまらない質問をしてしまい申し訳有りません。
回答してくださった皆様ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

単純なtypeミスですね。

```
b.lenght === 1
```

Answer (score 3):

指摘されているようにtypoですが、別のアプローチとして

```
function zeroPadding(n) {
    // 100足してしまえば必ず３桁になるので文字列化後に先頭の文字をとばす
    return (100 + n + "").substring(1);
}

function checkAttr(a, b, c) {
    return a + "-" + zeroPadding(b) + "-" + zeroPadding(c);
}
```